# Node postgres ECONNREFUSED in localhost

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

This issue is totally driving me insane. I spent months with this, trying to make a SIMPLE NODE APP WORK. I finally managed to make an APP work in a nice server (Heroku) and with mysql. Problem? The server only accepts postgres. And this is my nightmare. I just cannot make it work. Searched dozens of webs and problems, all of them with the same error log as me... but I just cannot figure what to do. I'm totally idiot at configuring things, I cannot even start programming my app.

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
>   at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>   at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
>   at TCPConnectWrap.afteeConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)

My start of server.js

> const pg = require('pg');
>   const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://myrole:12345@localhost:5432/mydb';

And here the error.

> var pool = new pg.Pool();
>   pool.connect().then(client => {

It crashes right at connection.

I did everything I searched for. I created "myrole" login role with all permission, password "12345", to connect to "mydb" database. I opened "pgAdmin4" application. Connected to "PostgreSQL 10" and "mydb". I saw that the first one connects to port 3000. I tried port 3000 in the connection string. I searched for the service at Windows. It's running. I JUST DID EVERYTHING and nothing works... I installed and made MySQL database to run in local in just 2 hours. But Heroku doesn't accept MySQL and I don't want to put any credit card. What's happening here?

Comment: Are you manually able to connect to postgres using psql with the same creds?

Comment: Don't get all nervous, stop, think, and investigate. What is your `port` in `postgresql.conf`? What is `listen_addresses` set to? Is PostgreSQL running? Can you see it listen at the port with `netstat -a`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I'll put my situation here and hopefully help someone else.

I was testing some AWS Lambda functions and since the code runs in a container and the container has its own *localhost* so my postgres connection was failing because there is no postgres server running on the container. Remember that your machine's localhost is not the same as the container's one, if your app is running inside a container the instead of localhost use your machine IP.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you shuld include connectionString inside new Pool() as property of Object

```
var pool = new pg.Pool({connectionString}); pool.connect().then()
```

or here is a more detailed version

```
let c = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'mydb',
  options: `application_name=${app}&application_cmd=${cmd}`
};
const connection_string = {connectionString : `postgresql://${c.user}:${c.password}@${c.host}:${c.port}/${c.database}?${c.options}`};
const pool = new Pool(connection_string);
```

more details can be found here [node-postgres.com](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting#connection-uri)